# Target entity not found using Doctrine 2 ORM

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

In a ZF2 project, I have a "product" entity with this property definition :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Admin\Entity\Stock\Stock", mappedBy="product", cascade={"persist", "merge", "remove"})
 **/
protected $stocks;
```

And a Stock entity with this property :

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Admin\Entity\Product\Product", inversedBy="stocks", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
 */
protected $product;
```

When I call `./vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create`
I have this error :

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                     
The target-entity Admin\Entity\Product\Stock cannot be found in 'Admin\Entity\Product\Product#stocks'.
```

Before, the stock entity was in the `Admin\Entity\Product` namespace but I moved it and changed the namespace definition.

Don't understand... Any help would be munch appreciate

Comment: It could be that Doctrine doesn't like namespaces that go below the same Entity folder?  What are the namespace definitions you are using in each entity?

Comment: `namespace Admin\Entity\Stock;` and `namespace Admin\Entity\Product;` The strange think is when I launch the `orm:schema-tool:create` command on my local system (macOS), it works great ! On server system (Debian wheezy), it fails ...

Comment: If you change all of the entity namespaces back to just \Entity, does it then work on your server?  What version of Doctrine is each system running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution ...

On the production server, doctrine is configured with memcache ...

```
'driver' =>
        [
            'sympass_annotation_driver'    =>
                [
                    'cache' => 'memcached',
                ],
            'accounting_annotation_driver' =>
                [
                    'cache' => 'memcached',
                ],
            'admin_administrative_annotation_driver' =>
                [
                    'cache' => 'memcached',
                ],
        ],
```

To flush the cache :

```
telnet localhost 11211
```

and type `flush_all`

Hope it will help someone